# Create New Test Case under New Test Folder(s) in Rally

Tags: java, api, rally

Looking for code examples of how to create a new Test Folder(s) in Rally (with multiple folder layers) and have a new Test Case(s) created and added at the appropriate folder level. I see java examples online of how to create new Test Cases and add them to existing Test Folders but not any examples with creating new objects in both (Test Cases and Folders). Is there any examples online someone could refer me to or code someone can share of creating a new Test Case to a New Test Folder?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely this can be solved using an IDE? I believe intellij can do this automatically for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you ran into any problem when trying to customize the existing examples? The way you create a test folder is not that different from how you create a test case. To make sure that you set all the required fields, and to see what attributes exist on the object you are trying to create see WS API object model [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/).

I put together a quick example where a test folder and its child test folder are created, and then a new test case is created and added to the child test folder. See it [here](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-java-rest-apps/blob/master/addTCtoTF.java).

Comment: Thank you Nick for the example. I did take a crack at it but was running into a couple issues. This helped clear them up.